# How to connect to MySQL on a different port

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I ran `php artisan serve` artisan command on a Laravel app, it runs on port `8000`. However, I get a MySQL error when hitting a table: `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`.

My `.env`

```
DB_HOST=locahost
DB_PORT=3306
```

Comment: wamp server on and clear chache and check it this one worked perfectly.

Comment: I’m using a vagrant box not WAMP.

Comment: @LDUBBS check if you have mysql server running

Comment: It is. If I change the app url to what is in the homestead confit it works but if I do an ‘artisan serve’ and change the app url to it. It throws that error.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this problem occurs because of `cache`, run the below command and try to clean your configuration cache:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And if your problem is not solved try to change your `DB_HOST=localhost` in your `.env` file to `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, and changed to 127.0.0.1. The problem still persists.

Comment: Your `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` or `sqllite`?

Comment: It’s set to mysql.